# Change square to circle in Three.js PointCloud?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, point-clouds

I'm loading a .ply file using PLYLoader and rendering it using the PointCloud object in three.js.

```
var loader = new THREE.PLYLoader();
loader.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    var geometry = event.content;
    var material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({ vertexColors: true, size: 0.01 });
    var mesh = new THREE.PointCloud(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
});
loader.load(file_url);
```

It's working okay, the points are rendered correctly. However the points are rendered as a square. Is it possible to change them to a circle? If so, how?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372834/rendering-spheres-or-points-in-a-particle-system/27580073#27580073) old thread that shows the picture of a three.js sample. We can clearly see the circles. However [that](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_particles_random) same sample today shows squares (after they changed the ParticleSystem to PointCloud).

Thank you

Comment: The circles are probably from this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_particles_random

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this:

1. Use an image with a circle as the input [like this](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_points_billboards).
2. Use a `<canvas>` as the input (and draw a circle to the canvas) [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41518776/2065702).
3. Use ShaderMaterial and draw a circle with GLSL [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54361382/2065702).

Answer (score 0):

A solution is associate circle images to each Point Cloud.

Could you have a look on this example :

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_points_billboards

Maybe in that you have the solution.