# how to import colors from a .ply file in three.js when using ShaderMaterial?

Tags: three.js, point-clouds

So, i'm making a kind of visualizer using three.js where i need to import a .ply file. When i import it using this code:

```
loader.load(
  "/xxx.ply",
  function (geometry) {
    const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
      size: "..",
      vertexColors: true,
    });

    geometry.center();
    const points = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
    points.position.set(x,y,z);
    points.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
    scene.add(points);
  },

  function (error) {
    console.log("An error happened");
  }
);
```

I do get the pointcloud, but the points appear as squares.
[result when i use the quoted code, with square points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOsWT.jpg)

To get circular points, I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509156/three-js-give-particles-round-form/54361382#54361382) code, but I can't seem to get the colors from the .ply file - I always get a black point cloud, although the file gives me color information.

[result when i use the quoted code, with circular but colorless points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BC9HE.png)
[result when i use the quoted code, with circular but colorless points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTsoz.png)